# Case unistallation for sense hat

Tags: sense-hat

How do you open the raspberry pi case to install a sense hat? I want to see the actual hat, not just emulator. and also the actual pi.

Comment: Which case do you have? How did you assemble the case and Pi originally? What emulator?  Don't post essentially the same question that was closed for lack of detail; edit your original question.

Comment: See [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works
and [How do I ask a good question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)